Replace pandas column value by previous column value if cell contain a substring
I'm using Python 3.6.8. I have a dataframe df with columns name & sport. I want to replace value of sport if it contains substring "replace this value for".
My dataframe is generated using following code
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'],
                   'sport': ['tennis', 'replace this value for Jane', 'replace this value for Alice']})

So I wrote following code
row_num=df.index[df.iloc[:,1].str.contains('replace this value for')]
for num in row_num:
  df.loc[num,1]=df.loc[num,0]

But I'm getting following error
 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 0

Can you please help me to resolve this error?

It would be best to provide a [mre] of your dataframe and the matching expected output.

Don't loop, use vectorial code.
If you know the names of the columns, use boolean indexing:
pattern = 'replace this value for'
df.loc[df['col2'].str.contains(pattern), 'col2'] = df['col1']

If you don't know their name, either extract it from the columns:
c1, c2 = df.columns[[0, 1]]
df.loc[df[c2].str.contains(pattern), c2] = df[c1]

Or, if really you can't (e.g. because you have duplicated column names), use iloc + mask:
df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1].mask(df.iloc[:, 1].str.contains(pattern),
                                   df.iloc[:, 0])

Output:
    name   sport
0    Bob  tennis
1   Jane    Jane
2  Alice   Alice


The error you get is because you mixed loc and iloc, with .loc you need to use the column name and not its index. Just replace your last line by:
df.iloc[num, 1] = df.iloc[num, 0]

Edit as per the comments:
This will work for the the OP case but for other cases with index not numeric or numeric but not [0, 1, 2, 3, ...], use:
df.loc[num, df.columns[1]] = df.loc[num, df.columns[0]]


Good pick I had misread the question, that said this is not a good approach for two reasons: 1- you should not use a loop in pandas, 2- this would fail if the index is not a range index (e.g. index=['a', 'b', 'c'] which would raise an error).

Or index=[2,0,1], which would fail silently, replacing the incorrect rows.

@mozway , I exactly answered the OP question "Can you please help me to resolve this error? KeyError: 0" !

Sure, but if we go this way, replacing the line of code with pass would also "solve" the error :p

@mozway as you know pass has never solved anything ... unlike my answer ;-)

The pass was a joke, but I was serious about your solution being incorrect. Try with df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 'sport': ['tennis', 'replace this value for Jane', 'replace this value for Alice']}, index=['a', 'b', 'c']) or worse with df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 'sport': ['tennis', 'replace this value for Jane', 'replace this value for Alice']}, index=[2, 0, 1]) which won't yield an error but an incorrect result. Pandas is inherently designed around the index, using operations that ignore indices is not acceptable IMO.
